# Control Not yielding after Task.Result in a non Async Block

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I was experimenting with an MSDN sample. I came across the following issue. When running an `async` block of code from a button click event handler, with `async` pattern, it works fine (`button1_Click`). But for `button2_Click`, the control is not going beyond `TaskObj.Result`. What might be the reason for the same?

```
  private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//this works fine
    {
        Task<int> TaskObj = AccessTheWebAsync();
        string a ="I came here..";

        int y = await TaskObj;

        string a1 = "I came here also..";
    }

    private  void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//this is not working
    {
        Task<int> TaskObj = AccessTheWebAsync();
        string a = "I came here..";//control yielded here
        int y = TaskObj.Result;//something happened here
        string a1 = "Why I couldn't come here?";//why control is not reaching here?
    }


    async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
    { 
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");        
        DoIndependentWork();
        string urlContents = await getStringTask;
        return urlContents.Length;
    }

    private void DoIndependentWork()
    {
      IList<Int32>intK = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000000).ToList();
      foreach (int x in intK)
      {
          int y = x * 2;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What might be the reason for the same?

The difference is one **deadlocks**, while the other doesn't. When you `await`, you *asynchronously wait* by yielding control back to the calling method. When you use `Task.Result`, you synchronously block on the call. This leads to a deadlock.

Why? because there is something called a "Synchronization Context" involved here, which is responsible for some of the magic of executing your continuation (all the code after the first `await`) inside the same context it previously used, which in your case is the **UI thread**. Because you block synchronously with `Task.Result`, the continuation is unable to marshal itself back onto the UI thread, since it is waiting on itself at the `.Result`.

Instead, use `await` as with your previous button click:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//this is not working
{
    Task<int> TaskObj = AccessTheWebAsync();
    string a = "I came here..";//control yielded here
    int y = await TaskObj;
}
```