# Any reason to use async/await when the controller action is sync?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

Lets say I have a controller action that cannot be made async (for various reasons), but I have a service that (through several methods) calls a rest service using `HttpClient`. Is there any thing to gain by using the async client and using `.Wait` or `.Result`? Or would it be less performant to use the synchronous method?

So either:

```
//MyController.cs
public ActionResult GetSomething(int id)
{
    //lots of stuff here
    var processedResponse = _myService.Get(id);
    //lots more stuff here
    return new ContentResult(result);
}

//MyService.cs
public ProcessedResponse Get(int id)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var result = client.Get(_url+id);
    return Process(result);
}
```

Or:

```
//MyController.cs
public ActionResult GetSomething(int id)
{
    //lots of stuff here
    var processedResponse = _myService.GetAsync(id).Result;
    //or, .Wait, or Task.Run(...), or something similar
    //lots more stuff here
    return new ContentResult(result);
}

//MyService.cs
public async Task<ProcessedResponse> GetAsync(int id)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var result = await client.GetAsync(_url+id);
    return await Process(result);
}
```

Comment: IMO, the only reason to make service method `async` is a plan to re-write controller action as `async`.

Comment: @Marius: Curious to know what those "various reasons" are that prevent asynchronous controllers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any thing to gain by using the async client and wrapping the
>   method in Task.Run(() => _myService.Get()).Result?

The only thing you'll most likely end up gaining is a **deadlock**. Think about it, you're queuing a naturally asynchronous method on a thread-pool thread, where the ASP.NET already gave you a thread to process you Action inside. There isn't much sense in that.

If you want to go async, and think you'll actually **benefit from the scale provided by asynchrony**, then you should re-factor your controllers to be async as well and return a `Task<T>`, where you can `await` those asynchronous methods.

So I'd either stay synchronous, or re-factor the code top to bottom to support async:

```
//MyController.cs
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSomethingAsync(int id)
{
    //lots of stuff here
    await GetAsync(id);
    return new ContentResult(result);
}

//MyService.cs
public async Task<ProcessedResponse> GetAsync(int id)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var result = await client.GetAsync(_url+id);
    return await Process(result);
}
```

Comment: could you add an example of how a deadlock would occur by mixing sync and async code..?

Comment: Note that I'm not specifically asking about `Task.Run()`, but about any of the ways of turning a Task into a synchronous result (like `.Wait` and `.Result`). I've updated the question, so if there is any difference between these ways, please update your answer to reflect that

Comment: `Task.Run` or not, [blocking on async code is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: @eranotzap [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957902/calling-method-from-mvc-controller-hangs-due-to-async-await/32958101#32958101) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134579/keyvault-getsecretasync-never-returns/33134681#33134681) [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018115/control-not-yielding-after-task-result-in-a-non-async-block/31018255#31018255) [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540185/wcf-async-method-calling-hangs-up/31540341#31540341) (Note each word is a different link :))

Answer (score 2):

In your scenario, no there isn't a good reason, but lets add some functionality:

```
//MyController.cs
public ActionResult GetSomething(int id)
{
    //lots of stuff here
    var processedResponse = _myService.GetAsync(id).Result;
    //or, .Wait, or Task.Run(...), or something similar
    //lots more stuff here
    return new ContentResult(result);
}

//MyService.cs
public async Task<ProcessedResponse> GetAsync(int id)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var pendingResult1 = client.GetAsync(_url+id);
    var pendingResult2 = someAsyncOperation();
    var result3 = someSyncOperation();
    var result1 = await pendingResult;
    var result2 = await pendingResult2;
    return await Process(result1, result2, result3);
}
```

Now, since your request takes a while to complete, `someAsynchOperation` starts executing immediately instead of waiting for `GetAsync()` to complete. `someSyncOperation` is also being executed in the meantime.

Without the `async` keyword, you would not be able to use `await`, so it's better to have it if you plan to have asynchronous execution inside your funciton.

Comment: Note: if you choose to wait then use task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); instead of task.Result so it doesn't wrap exceptions in AggregateException.

Answer (score 0):

It gets interesting when do can do it like this

```
//MyController.cs
public ActionResult GetSomething(int id)
{
    var processedResponseTask = _myService.GetAsyn(id)
    //lots of stuff here (1)

    var processedResponseTask.Wait();
    var processedResponse = processedResponseTask.Result;

    //lots more stuff here (2)
    return new ContentResult(result);
}
```

now the lots of stuff here(1) is done in parallel with your async  task. (Or if you called your service twice for example). If you don't actually do a lot around lots of stuff here(1) then there isn't much of a point.